# does dryer lint come into my bathroom through the air vent?

Tags: ventilation

When I moved into my townhouse we were told we must put an exhaust fan into the basement washroom. We had someone do this and since then we have had dryer lint come thru the vent.

We have also noticed that we can only heat one side of the house. Only half our vents give full heat. Could these issues be related?

Comment: Where is the dryer exhaust in relation to the exhaust fan exhaust?

Comment: Did the installer connect the heating, dryer, and bathroom ducts?

Answer (score 2):

It's mostly a guess based on the minimal information provided, but I doubt you're seeing dryer lint. Dust fibers from clothing and toilet tissue accumulate on exhaust fan grilles. They need to be pulled down and cleaned at least annually.

Actually, the fan blades do, too. In some cases the moisture and dust conditions are so severe that the blades get completely coated and blocked over time, such that the fan moves virtually no air.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this isn't likely. Your bathroom is an exhaust, and your dryer is an exhaust -- running one to the other wouldn't make sense.

Start by looking around the exterior of your townhouse, between 1-3 feet off the ground. Do you see a dryer exhaust like one of these?

[image]
[image]

Note that you'd only see the square louvered panel or the triangular-ish hood, not the cylindrical ducts behind them. The triangular-ish one will have a damper flap up inside it.

If you see one of these, then turn on your bathroom exhaust fan and go back outside. Are the louvers or damper flap open, and/or do you hear sound coming from it? If not, good. Now go start your dryer (with clothes in it, so it doesn't overheat) and go back outside. The louvers or damper flap should be open at least partially, and you should hear the characteristic dryer air sound.

Assuming you only noticed the vent in operation when *either* the bathroom fan *or* the dryer were running, then the two aren't interconnected and the lint you're seeing is normal bathroom lint (toilet paper, bath towels, bath mats, etc) collecting on the vent cover (and inside it). This happens because when you shower/bathe the room gets really humid, and some of that humidity condenses around the vent as it's getting sucked out... then as the lint is getting sucked out, it gets trapped in the condensed moisture and any other lint that has already collected there.